# Updating php with homebrew led to complications

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, homebrew, mamp

My php version was 7.1.33 but in order to install a specific Laravel project I needed at least version 7.2. I'm using a Mac with High Sierra (10.13) installed.
So I installed homebrew and then this:

`brew install php@7.2`
`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
`brew link php@7.2`

According to `php -v`(in the directory of the laravel project) my version is 7.2.33, MAMP is using 7.2.8, so this is fine I think.

`which php` shows me: `/usr/local/bin/php`

and `php --ini` gives me `/usr/local/etc/php/7.2` where my php.ini is and `/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini` where the loaded configuration file is located.

In the browser phpinfo of Mamp gives me these paths instead:

php.ini: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/conf`
loaded configuration file: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/conf/php.ini`

When trying to 'composer install' in said project I get an error that I can't install some extensions. This extensions are listed in Mamp's php.ini but not in the /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini the terminal gave me.

I'm confused what to do to resolve this issue, did I failed to install php 7.2 correctly?
Has anyone an idea what exactly went wrong or how I can use the correct php.ini (the Mamp's one, where the extensions are listed) in the terminal when installing the composer of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just manually installed the extensions I needed, updating php worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to ignore the composer error; add the platform config to your composer.json.

For example:

```
{
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "ext-mailparse": "1.0",
            "ext-intl": "1",
            "lib-icu": "4.2.1",
            "php": "7.4.8",
            "ext-gettext": "1"
        }
    },
    "require": {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have all the extensions in the "require"-part. What's the difference putting it in config platform?

Comment: platform config let's you emulate the platform you want so you can just install packages that have these platform requirements

Answer (score 0):

The fact is, MAMP will use its own PHP version and configuration files and will ignore the brew-installed ones. Your terminal, on the other hand, will do the opposite.

So you need to tell your system to use MAMP php by adding its bin folder to the path:

```sh
brew unlink php@7.2
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Note: you should remove `/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin` from your path, check your `~/.bash_profile` file

---

If you want to keep system php and MAMP php separated, you could alias a different command for the mamp PHP:

```
alias phpmamp="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/bin/php"
```

and then invoke composer using it:

```
phpmamp composer install
```

Comment: How do I remove it from my path? I'm pretty new to the console/terminal

Comment: You need to manually edit your `~/.bash_profile` file, you will find a row toward the end containing "`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH`". Remove it and save the file. Then close and open again your terminal

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try that :)

Comment: Sadly the second option didn't work. "composer" is seen as input file and i get this: "Could not open input file"